# how to calculate month circular difference despite year?

Tags: python

I´m trying to calculate the circular distance between months to know the deacoupling between two processes.  So i have a data frame with some columns between which i wont to calculate the difference in a circular way. The months are not date but just numbers from 1 to 12. 
Let´s say

```
month1 month2
  6      8
  12     3
  8      5
  1      11
```

if i just do

`month2 - month1` i have some problems:

`8 - 6 = 2` and `5 - 8 = -3` are okay, but

`3 - 12 = -9` and `11 - 1 =  10` and should be `3` and `-2` respectively (the difference between december and March, and the difference between january and november)

so i try with

```
monthdelta.monthmod(start, end)
```

but start and end must be **date** and it seems that is not possible to define a **date** just with the month ignoring the year and day. If i define month1 and month2 as dates with the day-month-year the difference between december and january will be 11 instead of 1 as i need.

so it´s posible to define numbers as months? or something similar to use `monthmod` despite year? or just other way to do it just wih the numbers? 
any suggestion?

Comment: Why 6-8 = 2 and 1-11 is not 10? and 8-5 is not 9?

Comment: you are wright.. i made a mistake in the example. I just corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to the updated question:

This should work:

```
def diff_between_months(month1, month2):
  diff = month1 - month2
  if diff > 6:
    diff = diff - 12
  if diff < -6:
    diff = diff + 12
  return diff
```

Or the same in fewer lines:

```
def diff_between_months(month1, month2):
  diff = month1 - month2
  return diff - 12 if diff > 6 else diff + 12 if diff < -6 else diff
```

Which returns:

```
>>> diff_between_months(1,11)
2
>>> diff_between_months(11,1)
-2
>>> diff_between_months(12,3)
-3
>>> diff_between_months(3,12)
3
>>> diff_between_months(1,7)
-6
>>> diff_between_months(7,1)
6
```

Where the minus sign in `diff_between_months(1,7)` can be fixed if you want by changing `if diff < -6` to `if diff <= -6`.

### Answer to the old question (absolute difference between months):

`min(abs(month1 - month2), month1 - month2 + 12, month2 - month1 + 12)` should do the trick.

As a function:

```
def diff_between_months(month1, month2):
  return(min(abs(month1 - month2), month1 - month2 + 12, month2 - month1 + 12))
```

this returns

```
>>> diff_between_months(1,11)
2
>>> diff_between_months(11,1)
2
>>> diff_between_months(6,6)
0
>>> diff_between_months(6,9)
3
>>> diff_between_months(6,12)
6
>>> diff_between_months(5,12)
5
>>> diff_between_months(7,12)
5
>>> diff_between_months(1,12)
1
>>> diff_between_months(12,1)
1
```

If for some reason your months could be bigger than 12, add the line `[month1, month2] = [month1 % 12, month2 % 12]`

Comment: Thanks Swier and Simeon both answer worked even when i made a mistake in the example... now i corrected it because i also need to preserve the sense of the deacoupling. Not just the distance but also the sign of the difference to know if "month2" is before or after "month1". I try deleting "abs" in the function but it didn't work.. Can you help me again?

Comment: yeah, will look into it, give me a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
def diff(month1, month2):
    m_min = min(month1, month2)
    m_max = max(month1, month2)
    diff = m_max - m_min
    return diff if diff <= 6 else m_min + 12 - m_max
```

which gives the desired results:

```
>>> diff(1, 11)
2
>>> diff(6, 8)
2
>>> diff(8, 5)
3
>>> diff(12, 3)
3
```